# Removing internal testers from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have successfully deployed my Android production app on Google Play. I want to remove my testers from internal test so can install and use the production app. When I go into Manage internal testers and click on Remove Users its tells me that it has saved. However when I exit from the page, it tells me that it is not saved and if I then exit and return to the page the Remove Testers button is still active. Also previous testers get the following message when they access Google Play and go to the production app download screen:

You're an internal tester. This app may be un-secure or unstable

If any one could help me to remove this message I would really appreciate it. It looks very unprofessional to some high profile clients who were also app testers previously.

Many thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to do this is:

- Go to Play Console > Testing > Internal Testing.

Under the "Testers" tab scroll to the bottom and you should see this:

[image: Internal testing link]

Tap on the "Copy link" button. This will copy the Internal testing's binary link. Now send this to your internal testers. Once they open this link make they will get the "Leave the program" option (see picture below).

[image: Leave the program]

Once they tap this, they will have opted-out of your internal testing list!

p.s. If the "Leave the program" option doesn't appear on the top right of the screen ensure that the tester has selected the correct account if they have multiple accounts added on their Play store app! (see the picture below, its the square on the right side under the overflow menu).

[image: Select account]

Comment: I did this but it didn't work. Is there anything else I need to do in Google Play to close the test before using the link described above?

Comment: can you let me know which part didn't work? For example: did the users get "Leave the program"? sometimes they have to clear the cache of the Play Store app for it to update!

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I copied the link and then clicked on the remove button. It said I had been removed and that it can take a little time, but when I check now days later I'm still not removed.

Comment: Ok It has finally worked I see. It took several days to take an effect. Thanks

Comment: Once you click the button -- you can go to the `Play Store` app's settings on the user's device and clear the cache. It will force an update and all changes will be reflected

Comment: adding an internal tester is easy.  removing an internal tester is near impossible.  i've been struggling with removing a tester for over a week.

Comment: To everyone struggling, just delete the data and cache of the Google Play Store app

Answer (score 5):

After completing the accepted answer's instructions, your internal tester may still see the message. To fix this, first confirm that the test version of the app is uninstalled from the phone and that the `Google Play Store` app has been closed completely. After confirmation, have your internal tester go into their phone's `Google Play Store` app settings. To get there, open the phone's `Settings` app, click on `Apps`, then click on `Google Play Store` in the list. Your internal tester now needs to clear this app's cache. To do this, click on `Storage`, then click on `Clear cache` at the bottom of the page.

Now have your tester open the `Google Play Store` app and install your app the standard way. They should be able to get the production version of the app!

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. Clear and still works perfectly. Instructions are clear to non-tech users too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is my usual procedure:

1. If you have access to Play Console, remove tester from internal test track in **Play Console > Release > Testing > Internal Testing.**
2. Uninstall the app if installed.
3. Disable Internal app sharing, **Play Store > Settings > General > Developer Options**
4. Clear cache and force stop Google Play Store & Google Play services apps in **Settings > Apps > Google Play...**
5. Reboot device
6. Disable wifi / cellular, and open Play Store (you should get an offline screen)
7. Re-enable network and click "Try Again" or reboot the Play Store
8. Hopefully, the store version should now appear.