# "(Internal Beta)" appears at the end of the App Title on every Play Store/Google Play accounts

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, flutter-android

- This happens to all Google Play account (not testers only)

[image: Google Play Screenshot]

- On Google Play Console it's already in the production release stage and all stages of the testing release are inactive

[image: Google Play Console Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before this, I found that my Internal App sharing was on **"Anyone you share the link ..."**.

So it has to switch to **"Restrict access to email lists"**

[image: Google Play Console]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to deactivate your other tracks, and don't include them in your production.

Also, change your account and check if you are still able to see Internal Beta. If that's so, then [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64274616/removing-internal-testers-from-google-play) your current account from internal testing from the play console.

If not then turn off internal testing and check again.

Comment: I have done all of this solution, but thanks for stimulate me to find another solution